# Kibana: Unable to revive connection: http://elastic-url:9200/

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I installed on Centos8:

- elasticsearch version 7.3.1
- kibana version 7.3.1

`curl -I localhost:9200/status` is *ok*

`curl -I localhost:5601/status` --> *kibana is not ready yet*

In machine with centos7 (.226) all is *ok*

[image: screenshot 1]

**This is kibana log:**

[image: This is kibana log]

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

`Elasticsearch` 7.x.x requires cluster bootstrapping at first launch and `Kibana` won't start unless `Elasticsearch` is ready and each node is running `Elasticsearch` in version 7.x.x.

I will write steps which you would normally do on a real machine, so that anybody else could do the same. In docker it may look similarly, except that you are working in the containers.

Before we kick off, stop kibana and elasticsearch:

```
service kibana stop
service elasticsearch stop
killall kibana
killall elasticsearch
```

Make sure it's dead:

```
service kibana status
service elasticsearch status
```

Then head into `/etc/elasticsearch/` and edit `elasticsearch.yml` file. Add at the end of the file:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
  - master-a
  - master-b
  - master-c
```

Where `master-*` will be equal to `node.name` on each node. Save and exit. Start `Elasticsearch` and then `Kibana`. On machines with lower memory (~4GB and probably in Docker too, as it normally gives 4GB memory for containers) you may have to start `Kibana` first, let it "compile", stop it, start `Elasticsearch` and back `Kibana`.

On machines with puppet make sure that `puppet` or `cron` is not running, just in case not to start off `kibana/elastic` too early.

Here's source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html

Comment: Thanks Domin, but your answer is for Elasticsearch in cluster node. My installation is for elasticsearch in single node.

Comment: the same goes for you - put just your one node in cluster.initial_master_nodes